# Did JK make a mistake when she referred to a Thestral as "grazing"?

Tags: harry-potter, continuity, jk-rowling

Thestrals are carnivorous.

J.K. Rowling says as much, in [this article](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/thestrals):

> While somewhat intimidating in appearance, **these carnivorous horses** are emblematic of a journey to another dimension, and reward all who trust them with faithfulness and obedience.

They're implied to be carnivorous in the books, too - Hagrid feeds them raw meat, they sometimes eat birds, and they are attracted to the smell of blood.

However!
Here's an excerpt from *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 6:

> As he crossed the dark yard, the great, skeletal Thestral looked up, rustled its enormous bat-like wings, then resumed its grazing. Harry stopped at the gate into the garden, staring out at its overgrown plants, rubbing his pounding forehead and thinking of Dumbledore.

Grazing! On grass? There are very few outright mistakes in the *Harry Potter* books (besides dates and numbers). Even the famous Flint issue was explained away half-convincingly. But this seems to be one of the few instances! Unless perhaps it was grazing on garden gnomes...? Or perhaps insects...

Comment: Maybe the mistake was calling them carnivores?

Comment: I'm trying to think: one of Chandler's Marlowe stories has him notice a young couple... but were they /grazing/ on each other's faces or /browsing?

Comment: "Did JK make a mistake when..." - most likely.

Comment: Maybe they had meat plants. I wouldn't put it past them :D

Comment: @Lichtbringer Hagrid would 100% import meat plants for thestrals and then proceed to call said plants "cute"

Comment: It’s like a person chewing a pen.

Comment: It's also possible that what looked like "grazing" was really something more like rooting around for fieldmice or other small animals.

Comment: As @Bobson writes, grazing stands informal for the habit to take here a bit and there a piece to eat, without eating a full meal, disconnected to the original meaning of eating grass.

Comment: @Lichtbringer Mandrakes, maybe?

Comment: You're assuming they were grazing on _plants_. They might've been grazing on meat. Maybe someone had left meat out for them. Maybe there were many small animals they were munching on. If they were grazing on plants, then the garden wouldn't have been overgrown!

Comment: Time to write to Ms. Rowling and ask her whether Thestrals are obligate carnivores or facultative carnivores :)

Comment: "There are very few outright mistakes in the Harry Potter books (besides dates and numbers)." ... ... *Hahahaha!*

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I do not have a definite answer to your question. But: Have you never seen a cat or dog eating grass? They are carnivores as well, but same as many carnivores they eat grass for [mainly two reasons](https://www.cats.org.uk/cats-blog/why-do-cats-eat-grass#:%7E:text=Grass%20contains%20vital%20nutrients,all%20the%20nutrients%20they%20need.):

> **1. Eating grass helps with digestion**
> When cats catch and eat prey, they tend to eat most of the animal, including the bones and fur/feathers which can be difficult to digest and cause constipation. Licking and swallowing their own fur can lead to this too. If they can’t vomit these things up naturally, eating grass can help them to vomit them up or act as a natural laxative, helping to break them down and allowing your cat to pass them more easily.
> **2. Grass contains vital nutrients**
> Grass contains nutrients that your cat may otherwise be missing from their diet, such as fibre or folic acid, which is why they may be attracted to eating it. Make sure you’re feeding them a ‘complete’ cat food which should have all the nutrients they need.

This is also true for e.g. [lions and tigers](https://www.quora.com/Do-lions-eat-grass-when-necessary) or [bears](https://www.quora.com/Will-a-bear-resort-to-eating-grass-and-leaves-if-there-is-no-other-food-perhaps-it-s-ill-and-can-t-catch-an-animal-there-s-a-blight-on-the-nuts-and-berries) (although technically they are omnivores). It is not a big stretch to think that the same could be true for thestrals.

Comment: Like all cats, mine does indeed  eat the occasional bit of grass. It would be a real push to describe her as grazing though.  Grazing, to me, implies a prolonged period for sustenance.

Comment: @BangBang "Graze" originally and etymologically means "eat grass". "Eat over a prolonged period" is a related but separate meaning. FWIW, though, if you've seen a cat eat grass, you know they aren't very good at it, and spend a lot of time to accomplish very little.

Comment: +1 Cats are obligate carnivores, although they may hit grass to assist with digestion. [Dogs are omnivores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog#Diet), not carnivores.

Comment: FWIW, I've often seen "grazing" used for "I'm just going to eat a few selected bits" when it comes to potlucks and buffets and people. "Do you need a plate?" "No, I'm just grazing."

Comment: My cat regularly eats wheatgrass several times day (I keep planting it for him in a pot) - on each occasion only for a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Sneftel you may want to look up the etymological fallacy. Whilst the word grey may have originally and etymologically meant simply "eat grass", that is not how it is generally understood today

Comment: It is also how it is understood today, yes.

Comment: Chickens catch and eat small animals, but will also eat grass. They can't live on grass blades alone, though.

Comment: @Lexible: An obligate carnivore _must_ eat meat in order to survive. However, being an obligate carnivore does not mean that you could not possibly eat plant-based items for sustenance. Cats tend not to eat plant-based materials for sustenance, but they are perfectly capable of doing so (just not exclusively, they must at least have _some_ meat as well)  and have been observed doing so. Cats are biologically capable of grazing for at least a subset of their meals, if they were so inclined.

Comment: @Tristan: The quote under review here very much is referring to a thestral eating some grass, and not stressing the length of time that it has spent (or will spend) doing so. Your argument about what's commonly understood today just doesn't apply to the actual topic of the question - regardless of it being correct.

Comment: @Flater I wasn't claiming it was. I was disagreeing with sneftel's response to bangbang's comment

Comment: @Sneftel as a child I sometimes ate grass. I don't know anyone who would describe that as me having used to graze (as opposed "used to eat grass"), and I would certainly interpret someone saying their child "used to graze" as meaning they used to continuously snack throughout the day rather than eat in discrete meals

Comment: @Tristan I'm just going by the dictionary. Usage and connotations are regional and personal.

Comment: "This is also true for e.g. lions and tigers or bears" Oh my!

Comment: @Sneftel whilst dictionaries are generally descriptive, the order they list sense of a word frequently lags dramatically behind shifts in usage. As a native speaker of Standard Southern British English (which is essentially the same variety JKR is writing in, excepting direct speech of her characters), I am certain that that is not how the word is generally understood in SSBE

Comment: @Sneftel Which dictionary are you referring to, exactly? The four dictionaries I’ve just checked all disagree with your claim: _graze_ does not currently mean ‘eat grass’ in just any old sense: it means variations of “(of cattle, sheep, etc.) eat grass in a field”. If you put some grass on a plate and serve it to me and I eat it, I am not grazing according to any definition – dictionary-, usage- or connotation-based.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graze

Comment: The herbivore/omnivore/carnivore distinction isn't as clear-cut in practice as they may teach children, and as people may commonly believe (the same could be said of many things...). It's not particularly uncommon for herbivores to eat meat, too.

Comment: I like this answer! I favor a combination of this and Mooz's point that perhaps there were small animals (eg insects) amongst the plants. Wolves - also carnivores - apparently eat "even insects and earthworms. Grass and berries too are sometimes eaten". So, perhaps the thestral was rooting around, munching grass and select plants here and there, with small animals where it could find them. This could look like grazing. https://wolfsanctuarypa.org/2016/10/14/much-food-wolves-eat/

Comment: *or maybe I should attribute that point to Bobson above in the comments

Answer (score 8):

Of course I don't have any particular insight into what was intended, but it seems to me that the most likely explanation is that JKR was using "carnivorous" to mean that they eat meat, not that they *exclusively* eat meat, just as the word is sometimes used as an antonym to "vegetarian" when talking about people. As they are also "horses", it is not unreasonable to imagine that they can eat substantial amounts of grass, even if they prefer meat when available.

Answer (score 5):

## Grazing need not mean *grass*

Yes, traditionally "grazing" refers to animals grazing in a field and eating plants and grasses, but in this case it could mean that they were grazing on meats.

The term 'grazing' gets applied to people eating small amounts over a prolonged period. It has evolved to even include meats and other deli products.

See: '[Grazing platters](https://www.google.com/search?q=grazing%20platters)'

If you'll recall, in *Order of the Phoenix*, when Harry encounters the Thestrals in the forest with Luna, they are actually pretty calmly looking around and picking at meats thrown at them. This is not the 'normal' behaviour of a carnivorous animal, who are more often seen 'feasting' and 'gorging' rather than 'grazing'.

It's possibly a symptom of them being domesticated and possible similar to horses - they actually share *many* similarities to horse behaviours!

Comment: I didn't vote either way, but this seems like a somewhat implausible reading of the text TBH.

Comment: For what it's worth, as a native English speaker, I would _never_ understand _grazing_ to mean anything other than eating grass except in the very specific case of it being used to describe an activity done by a human. If you are referring to an animal grazing, then that animal is eating grass, not meat.

Comment: @terdon Only a Sith deals in absolutes!

Comment: @terdon: Strongly agreed, the figurative sense of grazing is restricted to humans and it’s a big stretch to read Rowling as meaning that here.  On the other hand, grazing for animals isn’t *quite* as narrow as just grass — in both technical and colloquial usage it includes at least other low-growing plants ([example](https://www.rewildingbritain.org.uk/reintroductions-key-species/the-role-of-grazers-and-browsers)), and in colloquial usage it can also often include bushes/trees ([example](https://www.alamy.com/small-group-of-female-impalas-grazing-on-thorn-bushes-image369529246.html)).

Comment: @PLL oh, yes, absolutely. My bad there, I would understand _grazing_ as munching on plant matter, be it grass or shrub or leaf.

Comment: The idea that the thestral could have been eating something other than plants crossed my mind too! A good thought - perhaps it was munching away on bugs or worms or other small animals within the plant matter. I'm much less convinced by the application of the human-at-a-potluck sense of the word though.